# In my play project, I cannot find project/build.scala

Tags: playframework

I wish to connect mysql in my play project then I am setting the dependency of Mysql driver.

Online tutorial let me add

val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    ...
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
    ...
)

to project/build.scala
But I don't have this file in my project folder, and I only have build.properties and plugins.sbt

Hope someone can give me a help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In play 2.2, it has been replaced with build.sbt

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/SBTDependencies